# Internal Server error when using ToListAsync() or CountAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using this code to return  a list of objects in an Api:

```
 [HttpGet("/api/product")]
public async Task<QueryResultResource<PositionResource>> GetProducts(JobQueryResource queryObjResource)
{
    var jobs = await context.Job.ToListAsync();

    var projects = await context.Project.ToListAsync();

    var volunteerships = await context.Volunteership.ToListAsync();

    var internships = await context.Internship.ToListAsync();

    var products1 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Job>, IEnumerable<PositionResource>>(jobs);
    foreach (var p in products1)
        p.ProductType = "Job";

    var products2 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Project>, IEnumerable<PositionResource>>(projects);
    foreach (var p in products2)
        p.ProductType = "Project";

    var products3 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Volunteership>, IEnumerable<PositionResource>>(volunteerships);
    foreach (var p in products3)
        p.ProductType = "Volunteership";

    var products4 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Internship>, IEnumerable<PositionResource>>(internships);
    foreach (var p in products4)
        p.ProductType = "Internship";

    var products = products1.Concat(products2).Concat(products3).Concat(products4).AsQueryable();
    products = products.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate);
    products = products.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).AsQueryable();


    var queryObj = mapper.Map<JobQueryResource, JobQuery>(queryObjResource);

    var result = new QueryResult<PositionResource>();


    var columnsMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<PositionResource, object>>>()
    {
        ["title"] = j => j.Title,
        ["city"] = j => j.City,
        ["Type"] = j => j.Type,
        ["Industry"] = j => j.Industry
    };


    products = products.ApplyOrdering(queryObj, columnsMap).AsQueryable();

    result.TotalItems = await products.CountAsync();

    products = products.ApplyPaging(queryObj);

    result.Items = await products.ToListAsync();

    return mapper.Map<QueryResult<PositionResource>, QueryResultResource<PositionResource>>(result);

}
```

I`m getting internal server error. I removed the await keyword and used Count() and ToList() for

```
 result.TotalItems = await products.CountAsync();
...
result.Items = await products.ToListAsync();
```

It worked with no errors and i don`t understand why.

Maybe it is one of the steps before that is generating the problem?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I get an error in CountAsync() and ToListAsync(). If i don`t use Async methods everything works

Comment: The first step in resolving an error is *reading* the error message.  Is an exception being thrown by this code?  What is that exception?  Catch it and examine it, or debug and pause on exceptions to examine it.

Comment: I use the debug and it stopped at CountAsync(). I am getting in console this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If the code runs async, there is no error message! That is why I didn't post the message...

Comment: That sounds like a client-side error in the browser.  What's the error *in the server-side code*?  Catch exceptions in your code and see if there's an exception being thrown.

Comment: `"That is why I didn't post the message..."` - Pro tip: When you want to fix an error, *reading the error message* is your first step.  Always.

Comment: What he is saying is that if there is an error when the code runs asynchronous. It is like hitting "Continue" "Pro"!!